# Using Merge in BatchInserter?

Tags: neo4j

I am using the BatchInserter in order to create some nodes and relationships, however I have unique nodes, and I wanted to make multiple relationships between them.

I can easily do that using the Cypher and in the very same time by using the Java Core API by:

```
ResourceIterator<Node> existedNodes = graphDBService.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(     DynamicLabel.label( "BaseProduct" ), "code", source.getBaseProduct().getCode() ).iterator();
if ( !existedNodes.hasNext() )
{
//TO DO
} 
else {
// create relationship with the retrieved node 
}
```

and in Cypher I can easily use the merge.

is there any possible way to do the same with the BatchInserter ?

Comment: Can you clarify?  If you create data (whether through java or Cypher) then when that transaction completes, the data should be there.  Which means that if you try to find it (via cypher MERGE or java) it should be there *AFTER* the previous transaction completes.   I don't know what you mean here by merge and batch inserter.   Is the trick maybe that if MERGE isn't finding the data, you're trying to MERGE it before some previous transaction that wrote the data has completed its transaction?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible in the batch-inserter, as those APIs are not available there.

That's why I usually keep in-memory maps with the information I need to look up.

See this blog post for a groovy script:

http://jexp.de/blog/2014/10/flexible-neo4j-batch-import-with-groovy/